# How do I change read/write mode for a file using Emacs?

Tags: emacs, file, file-permissions

If a file is set to read only mode, how do I change it to write mode and vice versa from within Emacs?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

> M-x read-only-mode

in very old versions of Emacs, the command was:

> M-x toggle-read-only

On my Windows box, that amounts to Alt-x to bring up the meta prompt and typing "read-only-mode" to call the correct elisp function.

If you are using the default keyboard bindings,

> C-x C-q

(which you read aloud as "Control-X Control-Q") will have the same effect.  Remember, however, given that emacs is essentially infinitely re-configurable, your mileage may vary.

*Following up from the commentary:* you should note that the writeable status of the buffer does not change the writeable permission of the file.  If you try to write out to a read only *file*, you'll see a confirmation message.  However, if you own the file, you can write out your changes *without* changing the permissions on the file.

This is very convenient if you'd like to make a quick change to a file without having to go through the multiple steps of add write permission, write out changes, remove write permission.  I tend to forget that last step, leaving potentially critical files open for accidental changes later on.

Comment: Hi, as stated in the answer from jfm3 `toggle-read-only` only toggles the read only state of the buffer not of the file. If you want to change the mode of the file use `dired` or execute `chmod +w` as a shell command on the file.

Comment: True, that is how you would change the mode.  However, if you toggle read-only mode on a buffer that points at a read-only file that you own, you will be able to edit it and write out your changes (there will be a confirmation question, of course).

Comment: Followed-up on the comments above and added text to the answer.

Comment: In recent versions of Emacs,  toggle-read-only has been replaced with read-only-mode.

Answer (score 15):

Be sure you're not confusing 'file' with 'buffer'.  You can set buffers to read-only and back again with `C-x C-q` (`toggle-read-only`).  If you have permission to read, but not write, a file, the buffer you get when you visit the file (`C-x C-f` or `find-file`) will be put in read-only mode automatically.  If you want to change the permissions on a file in the file system, perhaps start with `dired` on the directory that contains the file.  Documentation for dired can be found in info; `C-h i (emacs)dired RET`.

Answer (score 13):

What I found is `M-x set-file-modes filename mode`

It worked at my Windows Vista box.
For example: `M-x set-file-modes <RET> ReadOnlyFile.txt <RET> 0666`

Comment: In my opinion, this is the right answer to the exact question asked.

Comment: In elisp, this worked: `(set-file-modes FILE 438)` (where 438 is the decimal equivalent of `2#0110110110` or `666`).

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>CTRL + X</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL + Q</kbd>

Comment: Explanation? OP said file, not buf.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned up there by somebody else: **M-x toggle-read-only** would work.

However, this is now deprecated and **M-x read-only-mode** is the current way to do it, that it is set to **C-x C-q** keybinding.

Answer (score 6):

If only the buffer (and not the file) is read-only, you can use `toggle-read-only`, which is usually bound to `C-x C-q`.

If the file itself is read-only, however, you may find the following function useful:

```
(defun set-buffer-file-writable ()
  "Make the file shown in the current buffer writable.
Make the buffer writable as well."
  (interactive)
  (unix-output "chmod" "+w" (buffer-file-name))
  (toggle-read-only nil)
  (message (trim-right '(?\n) (unix-output "ls" "-l" (buffer-file-name)))))
```

The function depends on `unix-output` and `trim-right`:

```
(defun unix-output (command &rest args)
  "Run a unix command and, if it returns 0, return the output as a string.
Otherwise, signal an error.  The error message is the first line of the output."
  (let ((output-buffer (generate-new-buffer "*stdout*")))
    (unwind-protect
     (let ((return-value (apply 'call-process command nil
                    output-buffer nil args)))
       (set-buffer output-buffer)
       (save-excursion 
         (unless (= return-value 0)
           (goto-char (point-min))
           (end-of-line)
           (if (= (point-min) (point))
           (error "Command failed: %s%s" command
              (with-output-to-string
                  (dolist (arg args)
                (princ " ")
                (princ arg))))
           (error "%s" (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) 
                                   (point)))))
         (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))
      (kill-buffer output-buffer))))

(defun trim-right (bag string &optional start end)
  (setq bag (if (eq bag t) '(?\  ?\n ?\t ?\v ?\r ?\f) bag)
    start (or start 0)
    end (or end (length string)))
  (while (and (> end 0)
          (member (aref string (1- end)) bag))
    (decf end))
  (substring string start end))
```

Place the functions in your `~/.emacs.el`, evaluate them (or restart emacs).  You can then make the file in the current buffer writable with `M-x set-buffer-file-writable`.

Comment: When I try to compile my .emacs with this code, I get the message "Warning: save-excursion defeated by set-buffer".

Comment: @Alan, edited to put the `set-buffer` outside the `save-excursion`.

Comment: thanks for that change, which eliminated the warning. However, there's another one: "Warning: Function `subseq' from cl package called at runtime." I couldn't get rid of that even when I added (eval-when-compile (require 'cl)) to my .emacs.

Comment: See [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.help/10422). I have edited the code and replaced `subseq` with `substring` now. That should avoid the warning.

Comment: Now that I've gone over to Emacs 24, I get the message "Warning: the function `decf' is not known to be defined."

Comment: Try `(require 'cl-lib)` instead of `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))`.

Comment: When I use (require 'cl-lib), I still get the same warning. Note that I previously had no require statement for either cl or cl-lib.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking at a directory of files (dired), then you can use `Shift + M` on a filename and enter the `modespec`, the same attributes used in the `chmod` command.
`M modespec <RET>`

See the other useful commands on files in a directory listing at 
http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Operating-on-Files.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried out Vebjorn Ljosa's solution, and it turned out that at least in my Emacs (22.3.1) there isn't such function as 'trim-right', which is used for removing an useless newline at the end of chmod output.

Removing the call to 'trim-right' helped, but made the status row "bounce" because of the extra newline.

Comment: Forgot to include it … added now.

Answer (score 0):

`C-x C-q` is useless. Because your also need the permission to save a file.

I use [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs). It gives me a convenient function to solve this question. The code is following.

```
(defun spacemacs/sudo-edit (&optional arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (if (or arg (not buffer-file-name))
      (find-file (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:" (ido-read-file-name "File: ")))
    (find-alternate-file (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:" buffer-file-name))))
```

I call `spacemacs/sudo-edit` to open a file in emacs and input my password, I can change the file without read-only mode.

You can write a new function like `spacemacs/sudo-edit`.