# How do I open a file for edit as root with Aquamacs?

Tags: macos, emacs, sudo, aquamacs

I'm using Aquamacs to do most of my text editing, and would like to, selectively, open some files as root when editing them.

Is there a way for me to open some files as root with Aquamacs (and not the rest)?

I know that I can just start Aquamacs with a sudo command, but that's a bit too risky for me - I'd rather only have root permissions for editing files which absolutely require it.

Comment: `C-x C-f /sudo::/path/to/file`

Comment: I'm getting an error due to the second : in that command, telling me that the command is invalid, and the single colon version doesn't seem to escalate (it keeps telling me the file I'm editing is read-only)

Comment: What error exactly? Which version of Aquamacs (or Emacs) are you using? The single colon version is simply wrong, TRAMP syntax requires two colons.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had a typo in my command. After correcting, I'm being prompted for my root pwd, but the file opens up as read-only anyways. It may be a read-only file to begin with - is that something I can override with aquamacs?

Comment: Ah. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180910/how-do-i-change-read-write-mode-for-a-file-using-emacs. Mind putting your comment in as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can open a file as root using [TRAMP](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/) (bundled with Emacs since version 22.1):

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> `/sudo:root@localhost:/path/to/file` <kbd>RET</kbd>

If you don't insert the `username@host` part, TRAMP defaults to `root@localhost` when using `/sudo`, so you can shorten the syntax to

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> `/sudo::/path/to/file` <kbd>RET</kbd>